# Backup data from Macbook pro which won't boot

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, hardware

I have a 13" 2010 Macbook Pro which I am unable to boot. The most possible reason for it is that the Logic board has short circuited. I have detailed the problem in this separate post: [Macbook Pro - Faulty keyboard short circuit at video connector](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194381/macbook-pro-faulty-keyboard-short-circuit-at-video-connector)

I am going to submit the laptop to service center but before that I need to take the backup of the data. Is it possible to do the backup? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Target disk mode might still work.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD Not an expert on Target Disk Mode but won't it require for the logicboard to work to even start using it?

Comment: I was not sure, but you can do the surgery :)

Answer (score 2):

Surgery....

....pull out the hard drive, install it into an enclosure (a USB External hard drive enclosure) and simply plug it in as an external hard drive for another Mac without losing everything on the hard drive?

How to remove it:

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2010+Hard+Drive+Replacement/4305